# Command createIndexes failed: 'unique' is not supported on MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.UploadFromStream

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I am using C# MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.4.4.

Error message:

> 'unique' is not supported

Code Snippet:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\aagrawal\Desktop\Amit.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                var bucket = new GridFSBucket(mongoDB, new GridFSBucketOptions
                {
                    BucketName = "excelFiles",
                    ChunkSizeBytes = 1048576, // 1MB
                    WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority,
                    ReadPreference = ReadPreference.Secondary
                });

                var id = bucket.UploadFromStream(fileName, file);
            }
```

Complete Stack trace:

> at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId
>   connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.Execute(IConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocol[TResult](IWireProtocol`1
>   protocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.Command[TResult](DatabaseNamespace
>   databaseNamespace, BsonDocument command, IElementNameValidator
>   commandValidator, Func`1 responseHandling, Boolean slaveOk,
>   IBsonSerializer`1 resultSerializer, MessageEncoderSettings
>   messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocol(IChannelHandle
>   channel, ServerDescription serverDescription, ReadPreference
>   readPreference, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CommandOperationBase`1.ExecuteProtocol(IChannelSource
>   channelSource, ReadPreference readPreference, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.WriteCommandOperation`1.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CreateIndexesUsingCommandOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.CreateIndexesOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucket`1.EnsureIndexes(IReadWriteBindingHandle
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucket`1.OpenUploadStream(TFileId id,
>   String filename, GridFSUploadOptions options, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucket`1.UploadFromStream(TFileId id,
>   String filename, Stream source, GridFSUploadOptions options,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.GridFSBucket.UploadFromStream(String filename,
>   Stream source, GridFSUploadOptions options, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at CRUDOperationAzureMongo.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in C:\Users\aagrawal\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\CRUDOperationAzureMongo\CRUDOperationAzureMongo\Program.cs:line
>   110

Comment: Are you using a sharded collection?

Comment: First of all I am using Azure CosmosDB which uses MongoDB 3.2.0 in it's code behind.

Comment: And yes in this case I am using a shared collection.

Answer (score -1):

The C# driver checks if there is an index on `{ "files_id": 1, "n": 1 }` on your chunks collection. If there isn't, it will attempt to create a unique one with this specification.

In the case of a sharded collection this may go wrong. You can read up about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Unique-Indexes-in-Sharded-Collections). If you are using a sharded collection then make sure you follow [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#sharding-gridfs) part of the documentation.

You can also attempt to create a non-unique index with the above specification manually which, in theory, should resolve your issue.